# Read all CSV files in a directory into an internal table

Tags: csv, abap

I have a parameter and, on F4, we can choose the directory. I'm trying to figure out how to choose a folder and read the content of all the files in it (the files are in .CSV) to an internal table. I think I have to use TMP_GUI_DIRECTORY_LIST_FILES function. Hope I'm explaining myself. Thank you.

Comment: Please specify if you want to read the files from the application server or the frontend (GUI).

Comment: My mistake... forgot to write it. It's from the application server. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this manually: first [read the list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152919/get-the-contents-of-a-server-side-directory-in-sap-abap), the go through each file and [process its contents](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/fc/eb3c7f358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm). There may be some odd function modules to read CSV files, but be aware that many of them are broken - for example, they just clip the lines that exceed a certain length. Therefore I won't recommend any of them - personally, I'd implement the CSV import part myself.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this way... I'll see if I can get anywhere with your post. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the transaction `KCLJ` in your system you could analyze the coding behind it. This tool has an option to interpret `CSV` files so you might find interesting function modules that might help you with your tasks.

[image]

EDIT: I looked at it very quickly and the piece of coding you could reuse is `reconvert_format` from include `RKCDFILEINCFOR`. An example how to call it is located starting from line 128 in the same include.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it... I believe I have access to that transaction and I'll investigate about that function module. Thanks again.

Comment: There is virtually nothing there that can be reused in the sense of "used again as it is". You'd have to copy it over and modify it massively - no sense in doing that, IMHO.

Comment: Have not had a deep look at it but I was thinking of `PERFORM IN PROGRAM` in this case. If this cannot be done you would have to do the copy paste of the code with some adjustments. Still better than reinventing the wheel. If I have some time I will go deeper into it and prepare some encapsulated version of it.