# how can I read a specific file from a directory?

Tags: csv, abap

I have a directory with a lot of files, but I only want to read `.CSV` files.
I passed all the files in the directory to an internal table, and now I want to read these files (read the content of these files to the screen).

Comment: It might be important to know whether your application server runs on Windows or Unix-like machine. If it is the latter then the case matters!

Comment: Jagger, assuming that the files were read using a function module like EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING, that should be the case... although... after re-reading the thread below......

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use `EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING` as recommended for example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152919/get-the-contents-of-a-server-side-directory-in-sap-abap), you could just delete all lines of the table that do not end in `.csv`:

```
DELETE lt_file_list WHERE name NP '*.CSV'.
```

Be aware that the CP/NP operators are case-insensitive (this is probably the intende behavior in this case).

Comment: I need to use the 'OPEN DATASET file_s FOR INPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING NON-UNICODE'. But launches the the error: 'Error to open file', in all files of the directory. the directory is on the server.

Comment: OPEN DATASET does not "launch" any "error"s. Please specify exactly what you're doing and what's happening.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself wrong. I did this:
OPEN DATASET file_s FOR INPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING NON-UNICODE.
    IF sy-subrc NE 0.
      WRITE:/ 'Erro na leitura do ficheiro ', tabf-message ,'.'.
      CONCATENATE 'Erro na leitura do ficheiro ' tabf-message '.'
      INTO texto SEPARATED BY space.
      APPEND texto.
      CLEAR texto.
     ELSE.
The result of this is the message "Erro na leitura do ficheiro". The files are not being open.

Comment: And have you tried to catch the actual error message as documented for OPEN DATASET?

Comment: The result of SY-SUBRC is 8. But I don't understand, the internal table have all the files.

Comment: As I said, try to catch the actual error message, and for $DEITY's sake, please read the documentation: http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapopen_dataset_error_handling.htm

Comment: Can you find back the files with AL11 ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. When I pass (concatenate) the info into the internal table, I was passing some wrong data. 
Thanks.